# codename one push notification meet error "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure"

Tags: ssl, https, codenameone

We have a web project which is always working fine, it just using codename one push api to push notification to our devices, but it suddenly get the following error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert:
>   handshake_failure

Below is the core code (same with codenamoe one demo)

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL("https://push.codenameone.com/push/push").openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
String cert = ITUNES_DEVELOPMENT_PUSH_CERT;
String pass = ITUNES_DEVELOPMENT_PUSH_CERT_PASSWORD;
if(ITUNES_PRODUCTION_PUSH) {
    cert = ITUNES_PRODUCTION_PUSH_CERT;
    pass = ITUNES_PRODUCTION_PUSH_CERT_PASSWORD;
}
String query = "token="  + PUSH_TOKEN +
    "&device=" + URLEncoder.encode(deviceId1, "UTF-8") +
    "&device=" + URLEncoder.encode(deviceId2, "UTF-8") +
    "&device=" + URLEncoder.encode(deviceId3, "UTF-8") +
    "&type=1" +
    "&auth=" + URLEncoder.encode(FCM_SERVER_API_KEY, "UTF-8") +
    "&certPassword=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8") +
    "&cert=" + URLEncoder.encode(cert, "UTF-8") +
    "&body=" + URLEncoder.encode(MESSAGE_BODY, "UTF-8") +
    "&production=" + ITUNES_PRODUCTION_PUSH +
    "&sid=" + URLEncoder.encode(WNS_SID, "UTF-8") +
    "&client_secret=" + URLEncoder.encode(WNS_CLIENT_SECRET, "UTF-8");
try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
    output.write(query.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
int c = connection.getResponseCode();
// read response JSON
```

I directly run the code in unit test, it works well.

But when I call the function from project (such as a button from webpage), the error happened.

I tried several way to solve it but still can not work, please give me some suggestion to fix the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens if the certificate is invalid or out of date etc. It can happen if your connection. I just verified our SSL certificate on the push servers and it's valid (generated by cloudflare) so I suggest checking the routes to the server and your version of Java. You should have Java 8 or newer with a recent enough minor update version.

Comment: Thank you! My java version:java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: That seems new enough. Try connecting to https://www.codenameone.com/index.html it has the same certificate and should work fine but if there's an SSL connection issue it should fail in the same way.

Comment: Yes, I think your side SSL is no issu. I just very confused, as when I just run the demo code in main[] function, it works well and device can receive notification. But when I package the function and call it from web service, the error pop up....

Comment: I have tried to connect "codenameone.com/index.html" and codenameone.com. Still get “javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure”. If I connect to others website such as "http://www.google.com", it works well

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same JVM on the server as you do locally? Maybe the certificate repository on your server was corrupted.

Comment: yes. JVM is same. Local and UAT and Prod Server all meet same issue.

Comment: Maybe it's related to routing. Try checking with traceroute and similar tools, maybe there's.a firewall or something else in between that's killing the secure connection

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Dear Shai, i have the same issue and i cant solve it,my java.version:1.8.0_101 , my code work fine from 3 years ago and nothing changed,any suggestion ?

Comment: 101 is really old by now. It could be that cloudflare changed things up with their SSL protocol (they handle some of the server availability/security aspects) so older JDKs might have broken. You should probably update to a 2xx version.